# SQL convert two digits (yy) to four digitis (yyyy)

Tags: sql

I used LPAD and LEFT function for query and I can get a 7 digits column.

```
Left(LPAD(id, 7, '0'), 2) as Year
```

First two digit is year (yy). Now I want to convert it to four digit year (yyyy).

How can I do it?

```
1249208 -> 2012
1122222 -> 2011
0911111 -> 2009
...

...
9301010 -> 1993
```

#### update

I use MySQL.
Data range from 1980-2014 so far. No more.

Comment: Does the database vendor you use (what is it by the way?) provide any smart way of parsing strings into dates rather than a string functions?

Comment: What range are the years?  1915-2014?  1970-2069?

Comment: Which DBMS are  you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Is there something to determine the first two digits of the year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Oracle, use the to_date function. 
The format 'RR' rounds to a year in the range 1950 to 2049. Thus, 06 is considered 2006 instead of 1906

```
select extract(year FROM to_date(Left(LPAD(id, 7, '0'), 2), 'rr')) as Year FROM test
```

Here's an example of it working:

```
select extract(year FROM to_date('96', 'rr')) from dual
```

NOTE:
The other format 'YY' will add '20' to the front of the year, so:
    select extract(year FROM to_date('96', 'rr')) from dual
will give '2096'

Answer (score 2):

If you're using MySQL, you can use the `STR_TO_DATE()` function and `%y` format specifier (for 2-digit years):

```
SELECT YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(Left(LPAD(datestamp, 7, '0'), 2), "%y")) as Year FROM test
```

MySQL follows the following for disambiguation:

- Year values in the range 00-69 are converted to 2000-2069.
- Year values in the range 70-99 are converted to 1970-1999.

(See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/two-digit-years.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
select case when substr(id,1,2)<50 then 20*100+substr(id,1,2)
else 19*100+substr(id,1,2) end
from test;
```